# How to create a custom animated launch screen in flutter

Tags: android, animation, flutter, dart, splash-screen

I want to create a launch screen with minimal animations(like rotating an image). From the documentation found [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/splash-screen/android-splash-screen#implement-the-splashscreen-interface) I thought it was possible to do so, using the method mentioned under the 'Creating a custom SplashScreen' section. But I have no idea where to start. I first created a flutter java project using

```
 flutter create -a java custom_splash
```

Then I tried to copy paste the code given in the documentation link inside the `MainActivity.java` file and run the app but the app simply failed to build. I also tried to use the rotate drawable inside `launch_background.xml` although it did rotate the image to a particular angle, it was static and not animated.

**Note:** I have not built any native android apps and java is new to me too

**EDIT 1:**
I guess I must display it as a view instead of a drawable. So I tried this. Created a file called `SplashScreenWithTransition.java` next to `MainActivity.java`

```
package com.example.native_splash;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import com.example.native_splash.mySplashView;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreen;

public class SplashScreenWithTransition implements SplashScreen {
    @Override
    @Nullable
    public View createSplashView(
            @NonNull Context context,
            @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        return new mySplashView(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void transitionToFlutter(@NonNull Runnable onTransitionComplete) {
        onTransitionComplete.run();
    }
}
```

and another file called mySplashView.java

```
package com.example.native_splash;
import android.content.Context;

public class mySplashView extends android.view.View {

    public mySplashView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
}
```

and a `view.xml` inside drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="90"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    
</LinearLayout>
```

Modified the styles.xml as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ViewTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/view</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Finally modified the AndroidManifest.xml as follows

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.native_splash">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="native_splash"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
            android:name="com.example.native_splash.SplashScreenWithTransition"
            android:resource="@style/ViewTheme"
            />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Now when I run it with F5 the app builds and runs but does not show the content in the view.xml although the Launch screen does show the LaunchTheme.
Is it possible to have simple animations on the launch screen in a flutter app? if so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: A couple questions.  Is this for only for Android or IOS as well?  The process is different depending on which platform you are developing for!

Comment: This is a topic that is exclusively on the native development side and will have nothing to do with the Flutter side. I recommend expanding your search from making an animated launch image in Flutter to how to make an animated image on Android/iOS in general.

Comment: @ArthurEKing for now I am only trying to do on android

Comment: @Abion47 I will search for it. But any links on that  topic would be helpful

Comment: The production build will load your code pretty fast. If you display you Flutter splash page as your first view and have only change once whatever you are loading in the background is finished, you should't have any issues just using it in Flutter, without having to use native iOS or Android code. Worst case scenario you would set the background color of the native apps as the same of your Flutter splash screen.

Comment: @JoãoSoares That's a valid point but I would like to try it just for the sake of knowing how it can be done. But for any real app I will definitely follow your advice. Thank you

Comment: @PratheeshRussell it's great that you want to learn more! Good luck with your app!

Comment: I dont think it is possible to animate the launch screen but I did find a way to create native animated splash screen in flutter.  https://medium.com/@pratheeshrussell/creating-a-native-animated-splash-screen-for-android-in-flutter-acd9c16d6587

Answer (score 1):

In MainActivity Add

```
@Nullable
    override fun provideSplashScreen(): SplashScreen? {
        return SimpleSplashScreen()
    }
}
```

Refer the following github example https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/dev/integration_tests/android_splash_screens